# Unable to install/run Python 3.6.x and 3.7.x with MacOS Big Sur

Tags: python-3.6, python-3.7, macos-big-sur

-I upgraded my mac os to latest MacOS Big Sur, after the update my application which previously used to run with python 3.6.x/3.7.x are now not opening/running

Python version 3.9 or higher are running fine.Is any way to run python3.6 or 3.7 in MacOS BigSur?

Answer (score 10):

I ran into a similar issue with Python 3.6 after upgrading to Big Sur.

I went to https://www.python.org/downloads/ and downloaded version 3.9.0.

I then had to re-install some of my python packages e.g numpy too with the new Python version and things seem to be working again for me.

Comment: Many libraries do not yet work with 3.9. Any idea how to fix this without breaking huge swaths of the known python universe?